# "hundred" and "pretty" pronounced respectively as [ˈhən-dərd] and [ˈpər-tē]

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, dialects, non-standard, metathesis

Merriam-Webster's *A Pronouncing Dictionary of American English* gives [[ˈhən-dərd]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hundred), [[ˈpər-tē]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretty), [[ˈtem-pə(r)-ˌchu̇r]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temperature), [ˈse-kə(r)-ˌterē], etc., as alternate ways to pronounce "hund**re**d," "p**re**tty," "temperature," and "sec**re**tary"?

My question is, in which parts of the English speaking world can one hear those words pronounced as such?

Comment: Googling "purty" in Google books makes it pretty clear that it is used in Ireland and the Appalachian dialect (although i wouldn't be surprised if it was more widespread in Southern dialects).

Comment: Actually, it's mostly found on old *Andy Griffith* reruns.

Comment: In the part of Scotland I'm from we pronounce hundred "hunner".

Comment: @Hot Licks: ... and Andy Griffith grew up in Mount Airy, NC, at the feet of the Appalachian mountains.

Comment: What's that in IPA?

Comment: @tchrist: My interpretation of the gist of the question is that in some dialects, a syllable properly containing a consonant-rhotic-vowel combination is replaced with consonant-schwa-rhotic.  The rhotic and vowel are reversed, and the vowel is reduced.  I know this to be the case in Applachia, but I could only guess where else.

Comment: @PeterShor - And made a career out of imitating an exaggerated Appalachian accent.

Comment: "Hunderd" is commonplace among literate Canadians.

Answer (score 2):

Much to my dismay, I pronounce pretty as purty. I also pronounce corner as somewhere between cawner and conner. I was raised (or raised up) in Atlanta Georgia (or Jaja or Jawja) as noted above at the foothills of the Appalachian Mountains.